# Time to register a service on Spring Cloud Eureka

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I wonder if there is any option to set on application to speed up the service registration on Spring Cloud Eureka.

Once the service is published to server eureka, it takes too long up to be accessible on Server Monitor page. I guess is something related to time to scan new servives published.

Tks.

Comment: see explanation in documentation here: http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/spring-cloud-netflix.html#_why_is_it_so_slow_to_register_a_service